# How can I fade a gradient background in and out from my div?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a div `<div class="base-action-card"></div>` that has a gradient outline. When in `:hover` state, the div gets a gradient background.

`transition` does not seem to work. I cannot see in MDN documentation what could be causing this.

How can I fade a gradient background in and out from my div?

I tried adding `transition: background 0.3s;` to the `.base-action-card` class selector, expecting the browser to keyframe the transition from `white` to `linear-gradient(180deg, #1FC1FA 0%, #4b67f2 100%);` over `0.3s`.

No keyframes are rendered.

Snippet:

```css
.base-action-card {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, white 0%, white 100%); /* Solid white gradient */
  transition: background 0.3s;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    inset: 0;
    padding: 2px; /* Set the width of the "border" */
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1FC1FA 0%, #4b67f2 100%);

    mask:
      linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box,
      linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    mask-composite: exclude;
  }

  &:hover, &:active {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1FC1FA 0%, #4b67f2 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="base-action-card"></div>
```

Comment: `background-image` is not animatable property.

Comment: You're a true hero. The mask gets me into `background-image` land doesn't it?

Comment: you can add transition over opacity and set the opacity both on `::before` and `:hover::before` respectively as `0` and `1`. The gradient background will smoothly show up and disappear on hover in and out. I posted an anwser but since it was downvoted I had to delete it (but then I undeleted... maybe I'll change my mind again). Good luck

Comment: `background` is a shorthand for 
    background-attachment,
    background-clip,
    background-color,
    background-image,
    background-origin,
    background-position,
    background-repeat, and
    background-size

Comment: `linear-gradient` is background-image in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradient's in CSS are treated as images, rather than colors, and can not be transitioned between directly. Instead, a workaround would be to animate opacity on a after pseudo element instead, keeping the before element for the border. Something like this.

We can also remove the duplicate height and widths off the base element, as well as the duplicate background colors

```css
.base-action-card {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 200px; /* only one height definition is needed */
  width: 200px; /* only one width definition is needed */
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;


  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    inset: 0;
    padding: 2px; /* Set the width of the "border" */
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1FC1FA 0%, #4b67f2 100%);
    opacity: 0; /* Start fully transparent */
    transition: opacity 0.3s; /* Transition the opacity */
    visibility: hidden; /* Start as hidden */
  }

  /* Keep your existing ::before for the gradient border */
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    inset: 0;
    padding: 2px; /* Set the width of the "border" */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Match the border-radius of the container */
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #1FC1FA 0%, #4b67f2 100%);
    mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    mask-composite: exclude;
  }

  &:hover::after, &:active::after {
    opacity: 1; /* Fully visible on hover */
    visibility: visible; /* Make visible on hover */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="base-action-card"></div>
```